# How to get Day,Date and Year from a date string in the format DD-MM-YYYY

Tags: php, date

I have a date string in the format DD-MM-YYYY .I need to get the day,month and year as separate strings.Is there a inbuilt function in php or should i use the string manipulation functions and write a function on my own.

EDIT:

What i have tried

```
$getdate = DateTime::createFromFormat("d-m-Y", $date);
echo $date->format("d");
```

error:

```
Call to a member function format() on a non-object in...
```

Comment: Have you tried something ?

Comment: @Rizier123 $getdate = DateTime::createFromFormat("d-m-Y", $date);
echo $date->format("d");    Call to a member function format() on a non-object in

Comment: *as separate strings* Do you mean as separate variables or that you can print them separately?

Comment: @Rizier123 As separate variables i need to populate textboxes for Day,Year and Month

Comment: You have to call $getdate->format('d') in your example, not $date.

Comment: Why is the question downvoted ? Comments are welcome

Comment: @techno (I didn't downV nor upV) But I think you may got the downV, because you didn't show any effort/attempts/research at the start when you posted your question. That's maybe why you got these. For more information about: [how to ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) or [create a mcve](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) or http://blogs.msmvps.com/jonskeet/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question/

Comment: @Rizier123 I did not say you downvoted :) Told so because i noted the down vote after i updated the question with what i have tried.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
<?php
    $year = date("Y", strtotime($yourDate));
    $month = date("m", strtotime($yourDate));
    $day = date("d", strtotime($yourDate));
?>
```

**Edit**

You can also this approach

```
$date = explode("-", $yourDate);
$day = $date[0];
$month = $date[1];
$year = $date[2];
```

Comment: I'm very glad that you found solution :)

Answer (score 2):

This should work for you:

(With this you have day, month and year as separate variables)

Here I just [`explode()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.explode.php) the string and save them with a [`list()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.list.php)

```
$date = "15-03-2015";
list($day, $month, $year) = explode("-", $date);
```

Comment: This is the simplest answer and probably the most process-efficient.

Comment: The new user @Mubin answered first and his approach works great too.I hope Rizier123 dont mind accepting his answer :) New folks need appreciation

Comment: @techno Np, You decide which answer was the best for you :D

Answer (score 1):

You bet! You can use the inbuilt DateTime class to parse a date, based on a format that you expect:

```
$format = 'd-m-Y';
$date = DateTime::createFromFormat($format, '15-02-2009');
echo "Format: $format; " . $date->format('Y-m-d H:i:s') . "\n";
```

Source: http://php.net/manual/en/datetime.createfromformat.php